# Adding days to date in Angular is not working properly

Tags: angular, typescript, date

I am trying to add 12 days to a specific date. but I am getting the new date as not expected.
Here is my code

```
addDays(days: number): any {
    let startDate = new Date(this.selectedDeliveryDate);
    let endDate = new Date();
    endDate = new Date(startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + days))
    console.log(startDate, endDate, days)
}
```

`this.selectedDeliveryDate = Wed Dec 08 2021 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` and
`days = 12`
I am getting the `endDate` as `Tue Feb 20 2024 17:49:13 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

**EDIT**
I have printed the following code to test

```
console.log((startDate.getDate() + days));
```

and selected `07-12-2021` as `start date` and `days` is `12`. I am getting the result like `712`. Its just appending the number of days to the day.

Comment: I am passing 12 to the function when function calling, so it is days.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-javascript-date) help you?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue. The issue is my `days` parameter is not integer, so the `+` operator just concatenating the two values. So before adding days, I just converted days to integer.

```
addDays(days) {
  days = parseInt(days);
  let startDate = new Date(this.selectedDeliveryDate);
  let endDate = new Date();
  this.freeSlotEndDate = endDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() + days)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
on your imports:

```
import * as moment from "moment";
```

Then, your funtion:

```
addDays(days: number): any {
    let startDate = new Date(this.selectedDeliveryDate);
    let endDate = new Date();
    endDate = moment(startDate).add(days, "days");
    console.log(startDate, endDate, days)
}
```

Comment: For everyone who doesn't know moment, it might be worth mentioning that moment has to be installed as a dependency: `npm install moment --save`

Comment: moment is imported, but still same issue

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on chrome and firefox and it works correctly for me.
What browser are you using?

chrome:

[image]

firefox:

[image]

Comment: tested in both browser